# Extract numerical values from a particular <div> block in a webpage

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

**Objective:** extract numerical values from a series of span blocks embedded in a certain div block on a remote server using curl

I need to extract some numbers from a status page and have identified the div block that holds these numbers.

The format is as follows;

```
<div class="stats-values"><img src="some-image-name.jpg"><span>[numeric]</span> <img src="some-image-name.jpg"><span>[numeric]</span></div>
```

The source is all in one line. This particular div block only occurs once and is easily identifiable through the class name but may contain as many as 6 or 7 span blocks, which is what I'm after; these span blocks have no ID or class.

I have no interest in the decorative images, only the numbers inside the span blocks, which I want to output either comma -or space separated.

I had imagine that it should be something like:

```
curl http://webpage.example.com/status | grep "<div class=\"stats-values\">.*</div>" | grep "<span>.*</span>"
```

I have tried a few examples that popped up in searches on misc. fora but to no avail so far.

I'd appreciate a pointer as to structure and syntax, be it grep, sed or awk.

Comment: check the character encoding after download, so that "<" is not  printed as &gt;

Comment: Use a proper tool, an html-parser, for parsing html, not text-parsing tools, because html is not text and could escape text-processing in many unpredictable ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl http://webpage.example.com/status             |\
    grep -oP '<div class="stats-values">.*?</div>' |\
    grep -oP '(?<=<span>)\[.*?\](?=</span>)'
```

first `grep` extract the related `<div ...></div>` block;
second `grep` extract the numerical parts within inner `<span>[...]</span>` blocks.

`(?<=pattern)` is PCRE positive-lookbehind extension to the GNU `grep` we enabled to use it with `-P` switch.
`(?=pattern)` is PCRE positive lookahead extension.

and this `(?<=<span>)\[.*?\](?=</span>)` means our pattern `[nuerical]` is exactly within those two patterns; and these are exclusive from the output and will return only the pattern inside that matched and found.

`.*` is greedy match (longest possible match); `.*?` is non-greedy (shortest possible match)